# Android Studio on a RamDisk

Tags: android-studio, ramdisk

`Android Studio` is a kinda slow. I was wondering if anyone has tried mounting `Android Studio` on a `RamDisk`. 
If yes, then what would be the optimal configuration to harness the best of a `RamDisk` with `Android Studio` mounted on it.

Comment: You many check this out: http://sekharengineer.com/2016/01/android-studio-speedup-build-times/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow instruction from bellow link.

http://sekharengineer.com/2016/01/android-studio-speedup-build-times/

It worked for me perfectly.

Here on Step 1 the recommend you to download "Perfect  ram disk" ,instead I used "AMD Radeon™ RAMDisk". you can try it too. download links given bellow.

http://www.radeonramdisk.com/software_downloads.php

Comment: And this is why you quote the relevant parts. That link is now dead.